# JSONFormatting on JSP

Tags: json, jsp

I have JSON data stored in a DB table in string format. 
Requirement is to show this on JSP page may be in some basic readable format(A table with two coloums-Name,value).

Please help.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert `jsonString` to `jsonObject` using [json](http://www.json.org/) or [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) parser API. Once you've *objects* then you can easily format the *data* and show them on web-page via EL, JSTL.

Answer (score 0):

See http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/javadoc/flexjson/JSONDeserializer.html

You this flexJson api to deserialize your JSON String and assign to the corresponding Object.

Now use your object to display whatever u want!

Comment: The problem is it could be any object that is stored in DB.I could have added a column for object. But it is not like that. Cant i just convert the JSON into some HTML?

Comment: I recommend you to have generic Key Value Kind of Object to make it easy! Now answer to your question. The simple JSON String will be delimited string. like this ....var myJSONObject = {"bindings": [ {"ircEvent": "PRIVMSG", "method": "newURI", "regex": "^http://.*"}]} The structure of this is entirely dependant on the type of objects you store. So, I dont think it is possible to do without knowing how the object would look like. If you tell me what your problem is and why you want to store a plain JSON without any meta data, I could give you some other solution

Comment: Thanks, Now i have the metadata. But should i convert the JSON into object in controller(Spring MVC) or in JSP? I am new to all this J2EE world... :(